Why do I get "invalid credentials (49)" when trying to add a new user via ldif in openldap on Fedora?
When I run this command:
ldapsearch -x -LLL -b "dc=example,dc=com" -s sub "(objectClass=*)"
I get in return, No such object (32).
However, when I run this:
ldapsearch -x -LLL -s base -H ldap://localhost -b "" namingContexts I indeed get:
dn:
namingContexts: dc=example,dc=com

That said, I am trying to add a new user to dc=example,dc=com. The issue is this command: ldapadd -x -D "dc=example,dc=com" -W -f ~/Documents/new_user.ldif
prompts me for a password, and ultimately gives me: Invalid Credentials (49). The thing is that when I viewed my /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}mdb.ldif file, I see the olcRootPW is set to a value and when I use that value, i still get Invalid credentials (49). How can I have valid credentials and add the new user?
Note that sudo -u ldap slaptest succeeds just fine, so apparently the config files are not broken.

Is olcRootPW set to a plain password or to a {hash} of some form? Is there an olcRootDN parameter as well? If you dump the database with slapcat and look for the entry corresponding to olcRootDN, does it happen to have a userPassword attribute set?
